# как определить при старте приложения что получена нотификация?

Tags: android

У меня есть нотификации (уведомления) которые приходят от GCM. Даже если моя программа закрыта, я кликаю на нотификашку и открываю прогу. В ней чищу кое-какие данные в бд, и показываю кое-что на экране.

Если пользователь получил уведомление, когда программа была закрыта, и не нажал на него, но потом открыл программу обычным способом, необходимые действия не выполняются.

Как мне определить при запуске программы, выводились уведомления или нет, если да, то каким образом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вобщем всем спасибо за ответы. Ближе всех был @pepyakin
Так как я юзаю БД у себя в проекте я сделал так.
когда получаю нотификацию, то в своем сервисе делаю просто

```
 public void broadcast(String messageType, final Bundle message) {
        if (!ScanActivity.ACTIVITY_STATUS) {
            new NotificationStorage()
                    .setTicker("Receipt")
                    .setTitle("Receipt")
                    .setBundle(message)
                    .setMessage(message.getString("receipt_id")).generateNotification(this);
            ReceiptQueue receiptQueue = new ReceiptQueue();
            receiptQueue.setReceptId(message.getString("receipt_id"));
            ReceiptQueueDao.save(receiptQueue);
        }

        if (ScanActivity.ACTIVITY_STATUS) {
            Observer.getInstance().send(MessageType.RECEIPT_SHOW, message);
        }

    }
```

тоесть тут моя проверка небольшая (открыто ли уже активити или нет).
если открыто - я шлю обсервером нужное мне. 
если закрыто, то сохраняю данные нужные мне в БД. 
Дале два пути:
1. юзер тыкает на нотификацию
2. Юзер открывает через лаунчер
В любом случае открывается активити, в котором я достаю данные из БД и если там чтото есть, делаю то что мне нужно. После этого очищаю табличку с этим данными. ВСЕ!)))

Answer (score 3):

Всё намного проще, чем пишут другие. Когда вы создаёте Notification, вы передаёте ему Intent, который содержит информацию о том, какую `Activity` запустить при клике на Notification.

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class); // по клику на уведомлении откроется `HomeActivity`
```

Так вот, достаточно просто добавить в этот Intent какие-нибудь данные о том, что это запуск из Notification, например так:

```
notificationIntent.putExtra("isStartedFromNotification", true);
```

Чтобы проверить это значение, делаем так:
В `onCreate()` у `HomeActivity` добавляем

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isStartedFromNotification", false)) {
    //делаем, что надо в случае открытия из Notification
} else {
    //делаем, что надо в случае открытия НЕ из Notification
}
```

Comment: Проблема заключается в том, что нужно делать действие когда пришло уведомление, то пользователь зашел в приложение, например, через launcher.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется вот эта [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399455/gcm-message-not-recived-when-i-am-out-of-the-app) может помочь.

Там пишется о том, что нужно зарегистрировать правильно `GcmIntentServiце`, который будет получать сообщение, даже если ваше приложение выключено.

Также даются ссылки на [Set up a GCM Client App on Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) и [Google Cloud Messaging](https://github.com/google/gcm)

Comment: если вы прочитаете внимательно вопрос, поймете что оно итак получает нотификацию когда выключено. я нашел решение ниже отпишусь. спс

Answer (score 1):

Обычно, приложение получает уведомление через `BroadcastReceiver`.
Можно из этого ресивера инициировать запись некой настройки.

```
void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    context.getSharedPreferences("gcm", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
      .edit()
      .putBoolean("notification_pending", true)
      .apply();
    // Показать уведомление и тд.
}
```

Когда пользователь открывает программу "обычным способом", нужно проверить, есть ли запись о том что уведомление ждет

```
void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("gcm", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean needToDoStuff = prefs.getBoolean("notification_pending", false);
    if (needToDoStuff) {
        prefs.edit().remove("notification_pending").apply();
        // TODO: Выполнить "необходимые действия"
    }
}
```

При этом когда пользователь открывает программу через уведомление, то этот код так же будет выполнен. Удачи!

Comment: в ваших рассуждениях есть 2 провала:
1) нотификацию можете размещать и не вы сами
2) запись в префы флага не поможет, потому, что если юзер "смахнет" нотификацию, то флаг в префах не перепишется - как быть в этом случае?

Comment: Про 2) Скорее всего не важно, смахнет пользователь нотификацию или нет — если не рассматривать совсем диких юзкейсов, то действие по входу в активити все равно нужно будет выполнить.

Comment: Про 1) не совсем понятно, а кто еще может размещать от имени "моего" приложения уведомления? И как это должно влиять на логику?

Comment: про 2 - http://stackoverflow.com/a/13029945

Comment: @DeKaNszn, да спасибо. Но я хотел сказать о том, что это обычно этого не требуется. В дополнение я бы использовал бы статический ресивер, так как во время смахивания "нашего" приложения уже может не быть в живых.

Answer (score -1):

Вообще штатными средствами для всех версий Android'а это сделать невозможно, остаются только хаки. Проблема в том, что к сервису управления нотификациями нет доступа штатными средствами.

Есть хак, через `AccessibilityService`, [описан здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367196/detect-a-new-android-notification/9632076#9632076), но проблема с ним, в том, что юзер должен сначала включить в телефоне этот сервис - то есть гарантии что это будет работать нет.

Второй вариант использование [NotificationListener](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html#NotificationListener), но с ним проблема, что работает только для версии Android >= 4.3

Дальше остаются нудные варианты, если вы сами размещаете нотификацию, то можно в момент размещения нотификации где-то что-то сохранять, правда при этом совершенно неясно как убивать сохраненный флаг, когда юзер сам убьет нотификацию. А если не сами размещаете нотификацию, то тогда только хардкор типа вешать сервис, который просматривает список активных задач смотреть сервис нотификации, выискивать среди них свою нотификацию и все такое прочее.